How to customise downloading UI for on demand instant modules in android
Currently when requesting another instant module using url deep linking, like so:
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
    intent.setPackage(applicationContext.packageName)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
    startActivity(intent)

a progress bar is shown at the top of the screen in a separate activity before the target activity is opened
screenshot
Is there a way to customise the downloading UI, to add a downloading text, or branding image, etc.?
Looked at the samples in https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/tree/main/InstantApps, and there doesn't seem to be any option, should I try raising an issue in issuetracker.google.com? (componentid:316045)

There is a codelab that explains it in details

Thanks for the answer, but I believe that is for when we manage the on-demand module download in a normal installable app using SplitInstallManager. In an instant app, we need to use deep linking to trigger download of another module since "Split Install API is not available" error is thrown
